# Javascript form validation not working for 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate my form using javascript. I want that if a user leaves an input field empty then he will see an alert and the form will not submit data to php file. Unfortunatlly, the code below is not working for me. javascript is not executing on form submit.

**javascript**

```
 <script>
 function MyForm() {
 var x =document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "")     {alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
   }
  { var y=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
 if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("age must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
 }
```

**form**

```
 <form name="myForm"action="game.php"onsubmit="return myForm()"method="post">



  Name: <input type="text" name="name">

 Age: <input type="text" name="age">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple typos in your code. A good way to find them is to use the console in the developer tools of your browser (try pressing F12).

Change

```
{ var y=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
```

to

```
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value; //removed the opening curly brace
```

and in your form change:

```
onsubmit="return myForm()"
```

to

```
onsubmit="return MyForm()"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to invoke myForm function first to make  it work

```
  function MyForm() {
 var x =document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;

  if (x == null || x == "")   
      {alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
   }
  var y=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
 if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("age must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
 }
 MyForm(); // invoke it here
```

Comment: the invocation is in the form's `onsubmit`. There's just a typo in there (first letter is lower case).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 typo issue in your javascript method. Try below method

```
function MyForm() {
   var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "")     {
         alert("Name must be filled out");
         return false;
    }
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
          alert("age must be filled out");
           return false;
     }
 }
```